# How to print at a specific DPI resolution in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have an area in my application that I would like to print. How would I go about printing a page at 300DPI or 72dpi?

So far, I've thought that I have to get the DPI first and set the width and height so the end result is 300dpi.

So if someone wants to print a 4x5 area at 300dpi then I have to take the width and height x current resolution to get there.

Comment: I think you can only print what is actually rendered on screen (i.e. 72dpi); so printing at 300dpi would not improve the quality.

Comment: That's the thing. There is no way to set the DPI.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried printed in a photo paper 4x6. heres what I did: for example if i have 1800x1200, ill resize the image by using this formula: scale = 72 / 300. You resize your image using Matrix the scale value you got from the formula. 72 is 72 twips (no way around this), 300 for 300 dpi.
it will get the desired result, more or less. in the end it sucks and flex never had a great printing support so abandon all hope. better use the native OS's printing service.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I think I understand. Do you have a code example? How did you use the native OS printing?

Comment: thats two questions already! here is an example: rundll32    shimgvw.dll    ImageView_PrintTo /pt   xxx.png   "printer name" thats in windows. i had a tough time with MacOS CUPS support and the MACOS's native file/image viewer doesnt support command line so good luck with that.